# WHERE clause fails with certain string literals

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have a database table that stores error messages, and I want to run various queries on them. First, I get an overall count by grouping them like this:

```
select MessageText, COUNT(*) from MessageLog group by MessageText
```

And the result is:

```
1  Input string was not in a correct format      4
2  Value cannot be null. Parameter name: Int     8 
3  Value cannot be null. Parameter name: String  1
```

Now, if I try to select messages by the text string, some of them return no results even though the messages exist. For example,

```
select * from MessageLog where MessageText = 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: Int'
```

does not return any results, even though the previous query shows there are 8 of them. What is it about this string that fails to match?

Comment: Could it be that there's extra white space in / after your MessageText?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you either have white spaces in your MessageText that you are not accounting for or you are doing something you are not showing us.  I ran the following query:

```
with MessageLog as
(
    select 1 as id, 'Input string was not in a correct format' as MessageText, 4 as count
    UNION 
    select 2 as id, 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: Int' , 8
    UNION
    select 3 as id, 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: String' , 1
)
select * from MessageLog where MessageText = 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: Int'
```

and got the expected results.

Comment: It looks like a lot of people hit on the main gist of the problem, but I selected this answer because of the same query. I am running my queries in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, and I copied the text directly from the results of the first query into the command of the second query. What I didn't realize is that the output had replaced what was originally a newline character with a space. I pasted my query into an Excel spreadsheet and that showed me the original text with the newline. When I add the newline character in place of the space, the query works as expected. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

It possible that the actual message contains white space that you are not accounting for in your second query.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is a white space issue, either trailing space or extra spaces inside the text string. Try using a trim on the fields before comparing them.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have white spaces at the end of string. For verify you can test:

```
select * from MessageLog where MessageText LIKE 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: Int%'
```

Or:

```
select * from MessageLog where TRIM(MessageText) = 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: Int'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try redirecting the output of that query to a text file, and then looking at it through `od -c`. There could be a hidden character in there.